# Wildcard locations cannot work in spring boot 2.4.1

Tags: spring-boot

Wildcard locations cannot work in spring boot 2.4.1

java -Dspring.config.additional-location=/work/*/ -jar test.jar

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location '/work/*/' must not be a pattern
```

What should we do to solve this probelm?

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:

```
java -Dspring.config.additional-location=/work/**
```

Comment: I am sorry that it cannot work, it throw the exception that: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from '/work/**' 。  The directory structure under wok folder is: /work/a/application.properties,,/work/b/ logback-spring.xml

Comment: Where did you find this writing rule? Is there any document?